# How to configure/ customize the "bower init" and "npm init" options?

Tags: git, bash, npm, terminal, bower

Whenever you write `npm init` or `bower init` inside your terminal, you're presented with a step-by-step walk through for initializing the `package.json` or `bower.json` files.

## Default `npm init` and `bower init` configurations:

[image]

## Customization?

It would be helpful to be able to customize this default configuration so you don't need to manually edit these files each time.

- How and where can I create a default template for these field options?
- Is it possible to update **ANY** part of the `package.json` or `bower.json` directly from the command line?

  - EXAMPLE: `bower update version 1.2.0 --save` ?
  - EXAMPLE: `bower update author "Justin O'Neill" --save` ?
  - EXAMPLE: `bower homepage "oneezy.com" --save` ?

Answer (score 1):

To change the version of your project, you can use:

```
npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease]
bower version versionNumber #To modify your bower.json
```

If you want to update both at the same time, you can use a gulp task.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into bower, but npm allows for some customization.  The npm command `npm config` (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) allows hierarchical defaults for answers to questions in the `npm init` process.  The --userconfig option can be used to specify config settings on a per-user basis.  Some common examples include:

```
npm config set init.author.name "Guy Cool" --userconfig
npm config set init.author.email "guy.cool@awesomeness.com" --userconfig
```

Also, running `npm init --yes` will select defaults for all of the config settings that are set.

It appears that additional customization can also be done, although I haven't experimented with it.  The official NPM website suggests creating an .npm-init.js file for more specific customizations (see the section labeled ["customizing the init process"](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json)).

The NPM package `config` can be used for setting up custom package.json files on a per-environment basis (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/config for more info).